# Is it possible to create solr core for materialized views

Tags: solr, cassandra, cassandra-3.0

I am exploring materialized views referring [this](http://www.datastax.com/dev/blog/new-in-cassandra-3-0-materialized-views). I have created a table and a materialized view as follows.

```
CREATE TABLE scores (   user TEXT,   game TEXT,   year INT,   month INT,   day INT,   score INT,   PRIMARY KEY (user, game, year, month, day) )



CREATE MATERIALIZED VIEW alltimehigh AS
       SELECT user FROM scores
       WHERE game IS NOT NULL AND score IS NOT NULL AND user IS NOT NULL AND year IS NOT NULL AND month IS NOT NULL AND day IS NOT NULL
       PRIMARY KEY (game, score, user, year, month, day)
       WITH CLUSTERING ORDER BY (score desc)
```

Next thing I need is to perform solr search on this. I successfully created solr core for for scores table and it is working fine. I was wondering whether it would be possible to create solr core for the materialized view also. Create core command failed for the materialized view, but is it possible in any other way?

> $ dsetool create_core test.alltimehigh generateResources=true
>    *--this
>   one failed*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately this is not currently supported.

`The prerequisite for creating a core with automatic resource generation is an existing CQL table`

at

http://docs.datastax.com/en/latest-dse/datastax_enterprise/srch/creatingCoreAutoGenIndexResources.html

Comment: can you please provide any reference links?

Comment: Amended the response.